# Button is not clickable with singlechildscrollview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I am trying to build a layout with basically 2 parts which one is scrollable and not the other. I have a button on the not scrollable one but it is not clickable

[image: what I want to achieve]

Here is the code

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration:
            const BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.secondaryBackground),
        child: const SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            child: ReturnButton(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0),
          child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.mainBackground,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
                  child: Column(children: const []))),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: i can't understand what you exactly want

Comment: You need to give a fixed height to the Stack Widget. So you wrap SizedBox with height as MediaQuery.of(context).size.height. Once you assign a fixed height tap gestures will work

Comment: It is not working
I want the red top part to be fixed, with the return button clickable (it's a custom widget, just an icon button), and the white part to be scrollable. When scrolling up, the white part goes above the red part

Answer (score 0):

try using Icon Button Instead, and provide it with the Icon and inPressed callback

```html
    IconButton(
  iconSize: 72,
  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
  onPressed: () {
    // ...
  },
),
```